# Android: SurfaceView resolution is lower than screen resolution

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am following a tutorial on http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/ to make an Android game loop. It works really well, except that my SurfaceView is only 526x320 while my phone is 1920x1080 resolution. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: what does `surfaceChanged` say about the `format`, `width` and `height`?

Comment: @pskink should I just print those values in Logcat? Sorry, I am new to Android programming.

Comment: yes logcat, use `Log.d`

Comment: @pskink format: 4, width: 320, height: 526.

Comment: seems its everything you can get from your phone...

Comment: @pskink oh that is unfortunate. Might you have any idea why I am not able to use the full screen resolution? The SurfaceView is covering my entire screen, but it is just low resolution or dpi, I think.

Comment: did you try TextureView instead of SurfaceView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that tutorial overrides `onDraw()` when rendering onto a SurfaceView Surface, which is a recipe for trouble.  Don't do that.  Don't extend SurfaceView unless you really want to draw on the View as well as the Surface.  (Its render thread may also continue to run while the app isn't in the foreground... maybe you should find a tutorial by someone who understands SurfaceView better.)

Second, the SurfaceView's Surface is allowed to be a [different size](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html).  You can set it to any (reasonable) size you want with the [`setFixedSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize(int,%20int)) method.

The default size of the SurfaceView should match the size of the View.  If you have a full-screen View, the Surface will be the size of the screen.

Comment: Thank you. setFixedSize was what I needed!